# mysql where clause with value before column

Tags: mysql, where-clause

WHERE clauses are usually written as:

```
WHERE columnName > 45
```

I'm sure I read years ago that it is inefficient to reverse it like this:

```
WHERE 45 < columnName
```

Does the optimizer care? How about for date/datetime data types? E.g. is this ok

```
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(1516142364) < dateTimeColumn
```

What I read might have been something to do with `BETWEEN`, but I can't think of an example - so bonus points if you can read my subconscious :-)

(Not that I want to have them reversed, but I saw it in someone else's code, and was wondering if it's only a coding-standards issue, or if it's an efficiency issue too.)

Comment: What did your test queries return to you ?

Comment: Note however that `WHERE LOWER('HELLO') = x` is more efficient than `WHERE UPPER(x) = 'HELLO'` (slightly contrived example which assumes a case-sensitive collation, but the same same holds true for many functions.

Comment: Thanks @Strawberry, that was probably what I'd been thinking of, so you win the bonus points for reading my subconscious :-)

Answer (score 2):

The optimizer does not care about the ordering of the operands in the comparison.  Traditionally, the column goes first.

Some languages (such as C) have different operators for assignment and comparison.  So, you can end up writing `if (x = 0)` when you really mean `if (x == 0)`.  The first does an assignment; the second a comparison.  In such languages, some programmers often write the constant first, because `if (0 = x)` would generate a compiler error.

I can see this habit carrying over into SQL, even though the assignment problem is not usually an issue.

Answer (score 2):

I can't imagine that there is a difference in efficiency. This is just a matter of preference. While I prefer the first form, there are cases where the reversed form makes sense

```
WHERE 0 < x AND x < 100
```

Is easier to read than

```
WHERE x > 0 AND x < 100
```

Note that in `x BETWEEN 0 AND 100` the limits are inclusive while in the example above they are exclusive.